# How to select the lines of a data frame between two symbols [ ] and ' ' with spark java

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this dataframe and I want to show from the `col("time")` and `col("testsuiteClass")` specific lines, like for example in the following data frame, my input is:

```
+--------------------+------------------------- +
|                Time|      testSuiteClass      |
+--------------------+--------------------------+
|[2021-03-26] Tracker|StartingSuite'org.opin...'|
|[2021-03-27] Tracker|StartingSuite'org.opin...'|
+--------------------+--------------------------+
```

What I want to get as output:

```
+--------------------+------------------------- +
|                Time|      testSuiteClass      |
+--------------------+--------------------------+
|[2021-03-26]        |'org.opin...'             |
|[2021-03-27]        |'org.opin...'             |
+--------------------+--------------------------+
```

Can anyone help me to achieve that using Java Spark dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_extract` to extract the date from the time column by pattern and `regexp_replace` to get rid of `"StartingSuite"`:

```java
Dataset<Row> result = df
    .select(
        regexp_extract(col("Time"), "\\[[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\\]", 0)
                 .alias("Time"),
        regexp_replace(col("testSuiteClass"), "StartingSuite", "")
                 .alias("testSuiteClass")
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_extract` to extract the relevant symbol patterns:

```
Dataset<Row> df2 = df.withColumn(
    "Time", 
    regexp_extract(col("Time"), "\\[.*\\]", 0)
).withColumn(
    "testSuiteClass", 
    regexp_extract(col("testSuiteClass"), "'.*'", 0)
)

df2.show()
+------------+--------------+
|        Time|testSuiteClass|
+------------+--------------+
|[2021-03-26]| 'org.opin...'|
|[2021-03-27]| 'org.opin...'|
+------------+--------------+
```